# How to change default https certificate for web services in Dataminder?

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate

When installing [Dataminder](https://dataminder.pro/), two web service ports are set up. One for http and the other for https.
A self-signed certificate is created during installation.
But we need to use a certificate from a certificate authority.

How do you change the certificate used on web service https port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the default self-signed certificate with certificates from a certificate authority the simplest is to replace
the DMKeyStore file (which is just a standard Java Keystore file) with a new Java Keystore file containing the new certificates.

Note that the new Keystore file must be named and placed at default destination:

```
DataMinder/Server/Config/Certificates/DMKeyStore
```

To start using the new certificates file update the DataMinder properties file:

```
DataMinder/Server/Config/DataMinder.properties
```

The properties to update are:

```
dataminder.environment.web.https.keyStorePassword=...
dataminder.environment.web.https.keyAlias=...
dataminder.environment.web.https.keyPassword=....
```

Update the properties and restart DataMinder. Now DataMinder will use the new certificates.

Note: The certificates are used both for the admin HTTPS and Web Service HTTPS ports.